# PrestaShop installing theme error

Tags: prestashop-1.6

When i try to install new theme both from ftp and my computer im getting following error:

> Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=89741 in
>   /home/fansport/public_html/fansportsklep.pl/classes/db/DbPDO.php on
>   line 91
>
> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to
>   ObjectModelCore::hydrateCollection() must be of the type array,
>   boolean given, called in
>   /home/fansport/public_html/fansportsklep.pl/classes/PrestaShopCollection.php
>   on line 358 and defined in
>   /home/fansport/public_html/fansportsklep.pl/classes/ObjectModel.php on
>   line 1495

I dont have any idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check "max_allowed_packet" in MySQL and increase the value. That could solve the problem.